# javaFX mouse event filter

Tags: java, javafx

i trying to make a mouse event filter but its not working ,the consume() method is supposed to prevent the event from happenning and  the label to stop showing the cursor location wheen exceed 200 units , but it keep showing it , any solution guys ?

```
    package javafxapplication1;
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.event.EventHandler;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
    import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
    import javafx.scene.control.Label;
    import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
    import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    /**
     *
     * @author Nadjib
     */
    public class nadjib extends Application {

         public static void main(String[] args) {
            Application.launch(args);
        }

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
            primaryStage.setTitle(" hello  ! ");
            FlowPane flowflow = new FlowPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(flowflow,500,500);
            Label label = new Label("label man ");




           scene.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED,new 
          EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){ 

                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                     label.setText("position x = : " + event.getScreenX() 
                 + " positoon y = " + event.getScreenY() );
                     if(event.getScreenX() > 200 ) event.consume();


                }
            });

            flowflow.getChildren().add(label);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're checking the value of `screenX` **after** updating the `Label`. So of course the `Label` will continue to update.

That being said, in the code you posted, there's no need to `consume` the event at all. Simply do nothing if the `event.getScreenX() > 200`.

The simplest way to do this is with a simple `if/then` block:

```
scene.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED, event -> {
    if (event.getScreenX() > 200) {
        return; // Do nothing
    } else {
        label.setText("position x = : " + event.getScreenX() + " positoon y = " + event.getScreenY());
    }
});
```

If this doesn't solve your issue, please edit your question and explain exactly what you're trying to accomplish. Right now, this *will* prevent the cursor locations from updating once `X > 200`.

Comment: its a good solution but i want to prevent the label from showing the location after the cursor exceed 200 using event filter  is that possible ?

Comment: @itjuba - I am confused. The solution above does exactly that. Are you saying you want the `Label` to disappear entirely when exceeding 200? The solution above stops updating the cursor location.

Comment: how to do it using event filter ?

Comment: Using `return;` in this case is a bad idea. The lambda block ends just after the ite, so introducing spaghetti code can only confuse the reader and it has no effect in this case. Usually the condition should simply be inverted, if the consequence is empty anyways, but in this case the current code code makes it simpler to do any cleanup required. `if (event.getScreenX() <= 200) { label.setText("position x = : " + event.getScreenX() + " positoon y = " + event.getScreenY()); }` Furthermore I don't see a reason for keeping to use sn event filter instead of an event handler here.

Comment: @itjuba "_how to do it using event filter ?_". I'm also confused; Zephyr is using `addEventFilter`... where's the problem?

Comment: @Slaw why in my code the consum() method not working it should kill the event right ??

Comment: It has already been explained to you itjuba: `consume()` IS working in your code, but the label is still updating, even when the event has been consumed, because you are updating the label *before* you consume the event.  Also, calling [`consume()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.base/javafx/event/Event.html#consume()) on an event will "stop its further propagation" along the hierarchy in the [event dispatch chain](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/processing.htm#CEGJAAFD), but it won't stop any logic in the event filter in which `consume()` is called.